# Exporting from PDF into XML automatically

Tags: xml, pdf, export

I have a PDF form which is editable using Acrobat XI Pro. I want to export the form data into xml on a button click in the form. Right now, I can add an action in properties (Execute Menu Item), and the user can manually save by choosing Save Type as xml. But the xml format is not the same like exporting directly by clicking 'Export' from More Options. Can anyone help on this? In 'Add an Action', there is no Export option.